# Typescript error TS1005: '=' expected

Tags: angular, typescript

I keep getting this error when compiling my app. TS v2.0.3

```
app/components/profile.component.ts(13,12): error TS1005: '=' expected.
app/components/profile.component.ts(14,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
app/components/profile.component.ts(16,10): error TS1005: '=' expected.
```

here's my code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { apiService } from '../services/api.service';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'profile',
    templateUrl: './profile.component.html'
})
export class ProfileComponent{
    product[];
    products[];
    productTitle:string;
    first[];

    constructor(private _apiService:apiService){
        this._apiService.getProduct().subscribe(product => {
            //console.log(product.result.products);
            this.product = product.result.products[0];
        })
    }
    searchProd() {
        this._apiService.updateTitle(this.productTitle);
        this._apiService.getProduct().subscribe(productTitle => {
            //console.log(productTitle.result.products);
            this.first = productTitle.result.products[0];
            this.products = productTitle.result.products;
        })
    }
}
```

I've read it could be because of updated syntax from TS and did updated it to latest 2.1.0 version and still got the error.

Anyone can help me on this?

Comment: The `product[];` is not a recognized Typescript syntax

Comment: can you help on what would it be the correct syntax in this case?

Comment: You need to specify a type for the array, e.g.: `products: any[];`

Comment: It depends on what you want to declare here. Instinct said that you should transform it to what cartant suggested. But I see that you are assigning `this.product` and `this.first` to a single element, which makes declaring `product: any[]` invalid.

Comment: also note, this is not new to 2.0 - this was never valid syntax

Comment: ok, i changed it to product: any[], but now i get this error because it's declared to any

 error TS7006: Parameter 'product' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Comment: By the way, subscribing in the constructor is not a good idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you need a type specifier for those lines, something like:

```
product:any[];
products:any[];
first:any[];
```

If you have the more explicit types available, use those instead.

EDIT

As noted in comments on the question, using `any` can have its own issues. In that case, you will need to find the correct type of each of these variables and replace `any` with that. One possibility is `product` but without seeing more of the code it's difficult to tell.